# Scala convert Seq[Object] to Map[String, Map[String, String]]

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala so I am a bit fighting with maps.

I have

```
val items = Seq[MyModel]
```

where MyModel (came from Java) contains getLang, getName and getMessage methods.

Now I need to fill up the

```
var loadedMessagesMap: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = ListMap.empty
```

to contain values grouped by lang in structure: lang -> (name -> message). Name property is unique. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
val result: Map[String, Map[String, Seq[String]]] = items.groupBy(_.getLang).map {
  case(lang, models) =>
    lang -> models.groupBy(_.getName).mapValues(_.map(_.getMessage))
}
```

It returns a `Seq[String]` because there might be several messages for the same language and name. Not sure how you want to handle that case.

Comment: Thank you. Getting there. I don't need to take care about multiple messages for same lang/name. This case will not happen (and they don't care about that too in FW backend). I did `models.groupBy(_.getName).mapValues(_.map(_.getMessage).last)` as a third row but I guess it is not the best solution:-)

Comment: @LukasJelinek It's fine. You can use .last or .head to get the a message from the list if you are sure the list will not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```scala
val models: Seq[MyModel] = ???
val mapped = models.map { model =>
  model.getLang -> Map(model.getName -> model.getMessage)
}.toMap
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, I am getting there just can you help me how to avoid this?
Type mismatch; found : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(String, String)], required: Map[String,Map[String,String]]. I need to return the value in: Map[String, Map[String, String]] . Sorry, newbie:-)

Comment: Hmm, so you want also to group by name? You're getting the error because I actually built a map of string to tuples there.

Comment: I edited the answer now, it should do the trick; let me know if that's what you're looking for :)

Comment: Nice. I don't get the comment about replacing _(model.getName, model.getMessage)_ though. Was that re an earlier version of the answer?

Comment: actually it is not necessary to group by name in my case, but the structure is needed in api I need to extend. The modification you did results only in one item, despite I have two models in Seq (same lang, different name and message).

Comment: @patrick yes, thanks for noticing that :). You can create tuples either by `(a, b)` syntax or by `a -> b` syntax.

Comment: @LukasJelinek that's actually because of the way maps work in Scala. To avoid this, consider picking a unique key for the language, such as name as you pointed out.

Comment: For example, creating a map `Map(1 -> "a", 1 -> "b")` will actually result in the map `Map(1 -> "b")` because the later mapping overrides the previous value which would be `"a"`.

Comment: yes, ok. Probably I will then need to create map of name -> message for every lang separately (in cycle f.e. for ....  list += lang -> listOfNamesAndMessagesForLang), right?